# How to output hex value from function that takes float inputs

Tags: c, if-statement, hex, return-value

Based on some of the suggestions given, I edited the code to show the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//function declaration
unsigned char float_to_hex(float value);


int main()
{
unsigned char hex_value=0x00;

//variable that stores returned hex value
hex_value = float_to_hex(1.0);
printf("The hex value is %x\n", hex_value);

return 0;
}



// Function definition
unsigned char float_to_hex(float value)
{
float atten_float=0.0;
unsigned char atten_hex=0x00;

if( atten_float == 0.0)
{
    atten_hex = 0x00;
    return atten_hex;
}
else if (atten_float== 0.5)
{
  atten_hex = 0x01;
  return atten_hex;


}
else if (atten_float == 1.0)
{
    atten_hex = 0x02;
    return atten_hex;

}
else
{
    atten_hex = 0x00;
    return atten_hex;

}
return -1;

    }
```

I edited the code by initializing the variables locally within the function definition. Also, i'm using "%x" to print the hex value of "hex_value", however, I'm still getting the same result, which is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using a value of non-static local variable that can work with `register` specifier `atten_float`. You have to initialize that to some value before using the value in the variable.

Also `atten_hex` is used without initialization in the `atten_float == 0.0` case. You should add initialization there.

Finally, you may want to use `%x` instead of `%c` to print a hex value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//function declaration
unsigned char float_to_hex(float value);


int main()
{
    unsigned char hex_value;

    //variable that stores returned hex value
    hex_value = float_to_hex(1.0);
    printf("The hex value is %x\n", hex_value); /* use %x instead of %c */

    return 0;
}



// Function definition
unsigned char float_to_hex(float value)
{
    float atten_float = value; /* add initialization */
    unsigned char atten_hex;

    if( atten_float == 0.0)
    {
        atten_hex = 0x42; /* add initialization */
        return atten_hex;
    }
    else if (atten_float== 0.5)
    {
        atten_hex = 0x01;
        return atten_hex;

    }
    else if (atten_float == 1.0)
    {
        atten_hex = 0x02;
        return atten_hex;
    }
    else
    {
        atten_hex = 0x00;
        return atten_hex;
    }
    return -1;

}
```